# Rails 3 UnknownAttributeError For Nested Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-attributes, simple-form

I've been getting the UnkownAttributeError for no particular reason, my models seem to be setup correctly...

**School.rb**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :id, :created_at, :updated_at

  #relationships
  has_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

My School model used to have the following, but it produced a MassAssignmentSecurity error for the user fields:

```
attr_accessible :country, :name, :state_or_province, :users_attributes
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :instructor_id, :first_name, :last_name, :school_id

  #relationships
  belongs_to :school

end
```

**new.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @school do |f|
  .well
    = f.input :name, :as => :hidden
    = f.input :country, :as => :hidden
    = f.input :state_or_province, :as => :hidden
  .well
    = f.simple_fields_for @school.users.build do |user_form|
      = user_form.input :first_name, :required => true
      = user_form.input :last_name, :required => true
      = user_form.input :username, :required => true
      ...
  = f.button :submit, "Next"
```

Note: `@school` is being populated in my new action from session information gathered on the previous page, I'm making a multi-step form. The school data is perfectly valid, if I was to remove the user form it would have no trouble saving the school.

The specific error message I'm getting in my create action:

> **ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in SchoolsController#create**
>
> unknown attribute: user

And the sent params looks a little like this:

> {"school"=>{"name"=>"Elmwood Elementary",  "country"=>"38", 
>   "state_or_province"=>"448",  "user"=>{"first_name"=>"joe", 
>   "last_name"=>"asdas",  "username"=>"asasdads", 
>   "email"=>"asdasd@sdas.ca",  "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}},  "commit"=>"Next"}

Is this maybe a bug with either Devise or simple_form? I'm using Rails 3.2.3

Comment: Not related to your question, but important for security: :password, :password_confirmation should NOT be attr_accessible, password is why we have attr_accessible, that the password in only settable in well defined actions. You then need to set it explicitly in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to change that

Comment: Meier, on that note is there anywhere I can find an example of this? I'm assuming I need to make a setter method attr_accessible instead? I'll open another question for this if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so apparently I needed to provide the symbol `:users` - the name of the relationship as my first argument for it to work.